# iOS8: Find out size class in code?

Tags: ios8, size-classes

I want to have specific table row heights depending on the device type. So I cannot define this in interface builder but need to know the current size class in code. How can I do that?

Answer (score 3):

The `traitCollection` property on UIView, UIViewController, UIScreen, UIWindow, and UIPresentationController can be used to determine size classes:

```
if (self.view.traitCollection.horizontalSizeClass == UIUserInterfaceSizeClassCompact) {
    ...
}
```

Implement the `traitCollectionDidChange:` method to see if size classes changed (for instance due to rotation):

```
- (void)traitCollectionDidChange:(UITraitCollection *)previousTraitCollection {
    ...
}
```

More info:

- [UITraitCollection Class Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITraitCollection_ClassReference/)
- [UITraitEnvironment Protocol Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/Reference/UITraitEnvironment_Ref/index.html).